# Java "int cannot be dereferenced" Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, dereference

So i have a method that should create an array list to hold randomized roll values for a dice. After the rolls are created it will add them to the elements of an arraylist in a loop. The line in which they are added gives me the error "int cannot be referenced"

Then, when i try to get the sum of those rolls in another loop i get the same error. Code below. I'm pretty new to java, I think the problem lies within the data types, arraylist being what it is and dice, faces, and sum being static ints.  Thanks!
i included the variable declarations from the beginning of my 
  class just in case.

```
 public class dice {
    static int dice, faces, max, min, mid, x,rolls,sum;

 public static void rollValues( int dice ) {

    //arraylist holding roll values
    ArrayList<Integer> rolls = new ArrayList<Integer>(dice);
    } 


    public static void rollRandomizer(int dice, int faces, int sum){
    //randomizing roll values 
    Random  r = new Random(); 
    for(x = 0; x < dice; x++){ 
        int roll = r.nextInt(faces)+1;
        rolls.add(x, roll); **<<<error here**
        } 


    System.out.println( "The roll values are: " + rolls);

    //summing roll values aka all the numbers in the rolls arraylist
    for(x=0; x <dice; x++){
           sum += rolls.get(x); **<<<error here**
    }

     System.out.println("The sum of the rolls is: " + sum);

    }
```

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is only visible in your `static rollValues` method, outside of that method you have a single `static` `int` field with that name.

Comment: BTW, having 8 mutable static fields is pretty dubious.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Integer> rolls = new ArrayList<Integer>(dice); // this is method variable, it's available only inside rollValues()`

And this:

`rolls.add(x, roll);`

calls rolls in 

`static int dice, faces, max, min, mid, x,rolls,sum;`